# Execute a script/stored prodedure when specific Error_Number is encountered

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I've created a stored procedure (`sp_dropUser`) to loop through and drop a user from all databases.

But many times I encounter error 15138 when a user owns a schema.

Hence I created another procedure (`sp_altAuthorization`) to alter the authorization of the schemas owned by the database user.

What I want to do is, whenever I encounter the specific error while executing `sp_dropUser`, then execute `sp_altAuthorization`, and then return to the first procedure and continue.

Something like:

```
CREATE sp_dropUser
    @userName

    --Cursor to DROP USER from each @dbName
   IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 15138
       EXEC sp_altAuthorization @userName, @dbName

   FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @user
GO
```

And `sp_altAuthorization` will accept the parameters and alter the authorization.

```
CREATE sp_altAuthorization
    @userName, @dbName

--build dynamic sql query
SET @dsql = N'USE ' + @dbName + N'
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA:: '+@schema + ' TO dbo'
EXEC(@dsql)
RETURN --not sure!
```

I was thinking TRY CATCH block could be used, but not sure how.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks @marc_s . I was not aware of the performance impact. I'll correct it in my procs.